# $\partial A$, when $A=\{x\in M: f(x)>0\}$ is the set $\{x\in M: f(x) = 0\}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

I have a question about the proof of this fact:

$\partial A$, when $A=\{x\in M: f(x)>0\}$ is the set $\{x\in M: f(x) = 0\}$

The proof says the following:

$$A = f^{-1}((0,+\infty))$$

Since $(0,+\infty)$ is open and $f$ is continuous, then $A\subset M$ is open.

Also, $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{F(A)} = \overline{(0,+\infty)} = [0,+\infty)$

Then: $\overline{A}\subset f^{-1}([0,+\infty))$

Now, $\partial A = \overline{A}-Int(A) = \overline{A}-A$. So, if $x\in \partial A$, then $x\in \overline{A}$ and $x\notin A$. If $x\in \overline{A}$, then $f(x)\ge 0$. If $x\notin A$, then $f(x)\le 0$, so $f(x)=0$

My question: how $\overline{A}\subset f^{-1}([0,+\infty))$ helps in the proof? I know that  $\partial A = \overline{A}-Int(A) = \overline{A}-A$. because $A$ is open, but what does the $\overline{A}$ does here?

Comment: It helps at the step "if $x \in \bar A$, then $f(x) \ge 0$". Also, $\overline{f(A)} = \overline{(0, \infty)}$ is not necessarily true, it is just a subset.

Comment: So I just need to change $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{F(A)} = \overline{(0,+\infty)} = [0,+\infty)$ to $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{F(A)} \subset \overline{(0,+\infty)} = [0,+\infty)$ and it's alright?

Comment: Maybe the paper considers the case of a smooth function such that $0$ is the regular value. Or $f$ is a Morse function and $0$ is not a maximal value. Then the result indeed holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is not true. Let $M=\mathbb R$ and $f(x)=\max(x,0)$. Then $A=(0,\infty)$ and $\partial A=\{0\}$, while $\{x:f(x)=0\}=(-\infty,0]$.

What is true is $\partial A\subset\{x:f(x)=0\}$.